# Text in monospaced font being compressed

Tags: spacing, typewriter, xecjk

When there're too many characters in a line, the white spaces are being compressed so as to fit in those texts. Normally this is fine. But now since I'm using a monospaced font and I wish to keep the characters vertically aligned, is there any way to disable this?

Below is a MWE. As you can see, the first line is being compressed. Characters in the second line has normal white space. Strangely, this only occurs on Chinese font, the English font acts normally.

[image]

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin = .75in}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of words should match the language. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to play with the margin widths? If so, changing `\geometry{margin = .75in}` to `\geometry{margin = .65in} will fix the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't read the documentation but with a bit guessing and the help of automatic translation: The punctuations have a rubber skip which you can deactivate:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin = .75in}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\xeCJKsetup{RubberPunctSkip=false}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。你好，世界。

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what a printed text will look like at this place.  If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like not at all!  A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look.  This text should contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the original language.There is no need for special content, but the length of words should match the language.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a comment, `CJKglue={},CJKecglue={}` are also needed, to replace the original flexible glue.

Comment: @Jinwen I guess you understand more from the docu than me ...